# Sumar 2 números con Flet con Python

Tags: python-3.x, flutter, flet

Estoy practicando y de modo de aprender Flet estoy realizando un ejercicio de sumar 2 números y mostrar el resultado de la suma, he modificado 3 veces el código. Ahora ya no me muestra error pero no me muestra el resultado de la suma.

```py
import flet as ft

def main(page):

    def button_clicked(e):
        if e.data == "+":
            txtresultado = (int(valor1.value) + int(valor2.value))
            page.update()

    page.add(ft.Text(value="Ingrese 1er valor", color="yellow", size=20))
    page.update()
    valor1 = ft.TextField(hint_text="", width=200)
    page.add(valor1)

    page.add(ft.Text(value="Ingrese 2do valor", color="yellow", size=20))
    page.update()
    valor2 =ft.TextField(hint_text="", width=200)
    page.add(valor2)
    
    page.add(ft.ElevatedButton(
        text="+", 
        on_click =button_clicked, 
        data="+",
        )
    )
    page.update()
    
    txtresultado = ft.TextField(hint_text="", width=200)
    page.add(txtresultado)
    page.update()
    


ft.app(target=main, view=ft.AppView.WEB_BROWSER)
```

Comment: No olvides dar el formato de código con triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una después del código. Es difícil que otra persona corrija el formato porque en python la identación es crítica.

Comment: Y por cierto: [no todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay 2 problemas, ambos dentro de la sub-función `button_clicked`:

(1) El primero, el argumento `e` no recibe un objeto simple, es un **Controlador de Eventos de Flet**, si imprimes **e**, saldrá en consola: `<flet_core.control_event.ControlEvent object at ...>`

Con lo anterior, esta línea `if e.data == "+":` no va a devolver "+", y como conozco poco de flet, por el momento no se cómo traerlo.
Sin embargo, similar a como ocurre en **tkinter**, **wxpython**, etc, cada evento debe tener su función; en otras palabras, debes tener una función para **sumar**, otra para **restar**, etc... entonces ese `if` es innecesario.

(2) El segundo problema, similar al primero, es que `txtresultado` no es una variable simple, es un objeto de tipo `ft.TextField`, por lo que al asignarle el valor a secas, se sobreescribirá el objeto y nunca va a desplegar nada en pantalla. Lo correcto, es asignarle el resultado a la propiedad específica del valor: `txtresultado.value = ...`

Entonces para arreglar el código, la función interna debería quedar:

```py
    def button_clicked(e):
        txtresultado.value = str(int(valor1.value) + int(valor2.value))
        page.update()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias aeportugal, con tu corrección de código ya me funcionas. MUCHAS GRACIAS