# Sumar y restar 2 números con Flet y Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flet

Estoy practicando y de modo de aprender Flet estoy realizando un ejercicio de sumar y restar 2 números, he creado mi función "`sumar`", "`restar`" pero cuando ejecuto el código me sale este error "*missing 1 required positional argument: 'valor2'*" es decir que falta un argumento.

```py
import flet as ft


def main(page):


    def sumar(valor1, valor2):
        resultado = valor1 + valor2
        return resultado

    def restar(valor1, valor2):
        resultado = valor1 - valor2
        return resultado
        
    

    page.add(ft.Text(value="Ingrese 1er valor", color="yellow", size=20))
    page.update()
    valor1 = ft.TextField(hint_text="", width=200)
    page.add(valor1)

    page.add(ft.Text(value="Ingrese 2do valor", color="yellow", size=20))
    page.update()
    valor2 =ft.TextField(hint_text="", width=200)
    page.add(valor2)
    
    page.add(ft.ElevatedButton(
        text="+", 
        on_click = sumar, 
        )
    )
    page.update()

    page.add(ft.ElevatedButton(
        text="-", 
        on_click = restar, 
        )
    )
    page.update()
    
    
    txtresultado = ft.TextField(hint_text="", width=200)
    page.add(txtresultado)
    page.update()
    


ft.app(target=main, view=ft.AppView.WEB_BROWSER)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es un problema muy similar al que [pusiste antes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/603994/80870). No entiendo por qué cambiaste el formato en el llamado a las funciones de eventos. Estas funciones esperan un argumento llamado **Controlador de Eventos de Flet**, típicamente asignado a un identificador `e`. En tu caso se lo estás asignado a `valor1`, por eso da el error en `valor2`.

La solución es definir correctamente las funciones internas.

```py
    def sumar(e):
        txtresultado.value = str(int(valor1.value) + int(valor2.value))
        page.update()

    def restar(e):
        txtresultado.value = str(int(valor1.value) - int(valor2.value))
        page.update()
```

Leer la [documentación de Flet](https://flet.dev/docs/)